# Swagger causes Azure App Service to all of a sudden double memory usage

Tags: .net, azure, memory-leaks, swagger, azure-web-app-service

All of a sudden an App Service I have took up a huge chunk of memory, like 250MB. This app is hardly ever used, and this happened at around 5AM local time so no users were using it and no devs were working. I actually have 8 App Services like this. Running on a B3 App Service Plan in a Test environment. They didn't all do this at the same time. I'm kind of at a loss for what to do. There weren't a high number of requests around these 'spikes' so caching shouldn't be why, even if it was 250MB is a big chunk for caching for these apps as they are microservices that return small json payloads. This app and all of the others are C#, .Net 6 running on Linux. Non Docker. Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this or where I should start looking to track this down?
[image]

EDIT 1 :I've tracked it down to Swagger. When serving up the json file, if I hit that endpoint multiple times the memory keeps going up every time and eventually it makes a huge jump. Each grey diamond is me hitting the swagger.json endpoint. You can see the memory climb with each request and then plateau when the GC fires offs, then after some more requests  we could the huge jump. And it just stays there, it never comes back down. I took some memory snap shots before I started, after the initial GC, then after the second GC and big jump.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There could be number of things impacting memory usage example number of apps on your App Service plan, if you have any slots, then each app has its own scm site and supporting resources.

Suggest you to go to the **Diagnose and Solve Problems** blade for your Azure App in the Azure Portal and search for Memory Drill down, Memory Analysis tool.

[image]

Refer to this detail video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWeutt1GvRs

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've watched that video and the part 2 video. It's helped get me into the memory world, but the problem is this screen shot and the video are for Windows stacks so I don't have all of the same tools. For instance I can't find anything named 'Memory Analysis' in my Linux based App Services.